# Very slow trigger Function on insert, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: postgis

Trying to setup a trigger function to set geom on insert and update. The update part is working fine and response time is great (0.08sec)

However my insert triggers runs for 12-13 minutes for a single row. This is really unacceptable.

The function is to calculate the geom based on lat/lng for the new inserted rows.

What Am I doing wrong here...

```
  CREATE TRIGGER tr_insert_geom
      BEFORE INSERT
      ON schema.table1
      FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.fn_test_table_geo_update_event();
   -- ALTER TABLE schema.table1 DISABLE TRIGGER tr_insert_geom;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.fn_test_table_geo_update_event()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN  
    -- as this is an after trigger, NEW contains all the information we need even for INSERT
    UPDATE schame.table1 SET 
    geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(NEW.longitude,NEW.latitude), 3857);
    RAISE NOTICE 'UPDATING geo data for %, [%,%]' , NEW.index_pk, NEW.latitude, NEW.longitude;  
    RETURN NEW; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION locates_data.fn_test_table_geo_update_event()
  OWNER TO write_user;
```

Comment: Is your intention to update the entire table in that trigger?  There's no predicate for the update statement.

Comment: yes, I want to update only the inserted row. How would I do that on an INSERT ?

Comment: `NEW.geom := ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(NEW.longitude,NEW.latitude), 3857);`

Comment: NEW.geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(NEW.longitude,NEW.latitude), 3857)ERROR: column "new" of relation "table1" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Context: PL/pgSQL function locates_data.fn_test_table_geo_update_event() line 4 at SQL statement

Comment: it's a `:=`, not a `=`.